# Express session flash message becomes empty after if else condition

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am trying to flash a message of a JSON Parsed response from **request module** that sends POST request to a third party api.

The below code shows how I handle the response (clientServerOptions is the request):

```
request(clientServerOptions, function (error, response) {
        console.log(error,response.body);
        var jsonResponse=JSON.parse(response.body);
        if(jsonResponse.ok){
        }else{
            req.flash('errMsg',jsonResponse.message);
            console.log(req.flash('errMsg')); // This line prints the message
        }
        console.log(req.flash('errMsg')); // this line doesn't, it's empty
        console.log('=======After redirect======');
        res.redirect('/entities');
    });
```

In the if else condition, console.log shows the req.flash('errMsg'), but once it's outside the condition scope. req.flash('errMsg') is empty.

> **Answer:** only call req.flash('xxx') at the place where you really use it, if you call it somewhere else before the actual use, it clears the value it stores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash messages are for one time use only, those get cleared once used.

Thus when you do `req.flash('errMsg')` in `if else`, it displays the message on console and then clears it. That's why on line after `if/else` you get the empty message displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just start with express and flash so wasn't clear about that flash is cleared once the get function is called. It works now:)